# How can play an audio file with plotting a diagram simultaneously in matlab?

Tags: matlab, parallel-processing, signal-processing, matlab-deployment, parfor

I would like to play an audio file Meanwhile plotting and updating a diagram. However, my audio file is interrupted. I would like to play audio file smoothly in background and update the figure at the same time.

```
for i=1:10
player = audioplayer(audio, Fs);
play(player);
scatter(x(i),y(i),'r.')
end
```

Comment: HI, It looks like you are trying to play a different sound in each iteration is that what intended?

Comment: yes something like it but it doesn't hear good :(

Comment: Try stopping the player at the end of the loop and use a pause somewhere

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that play is an asynchronous call: it means the program execution continues immediately after the call to 'play(player)'.

If you intend to play different files at each iteration, try waiting till the current file finishes, you can use something like:

```
while player.isplaying
    pause(0.001)
end
```

If you meant to play one signal and change the plots, move the play(player) outside of the for loop, and add some delay between each plotting point for example with your code:

```
player = audioplayer(audio, Fs);
play(player);
for i=1:10
    scatter(x(i),y(i),'r.')
    pause(0.1)
end
```

Example for one signal being played and plot being updated:

Build a chirp signal:

```
Fs = 16e3;
T = 10;
t = 0:1/Fs:T;
f0 = 100;
phi = 2*pi*t.^2*f0;
sig = 0.1*sin(phi);


% Start playing the sound:
player = audioplayer(sig,Fs);
play(player);


 % Plotting stuff:
dPhi = gradient(phi)*Fs;    
figure;
numPlots = 20;
N = numel(t);
for n = 1 : numPlots
    pause(T/numPlots)
    ind = 1:N/numPlots*n;
    plot(t(ind), dPhi(ind))
end
```

In general when plotting 'real-time' it is better to use tic-toc to figure current time compared to the time the audio started playing.
Also to improve performance it is better to set the xdata & ydata of the plots instead of re-plotting it every time as this action is much faster (doesn't update all other properties of the axes).

You can look at an old script I once shared to do 'real-time' plotting:
https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/14397-real-time-scope-display--simple-script-